# Concatenate action bar headercolor in android

Tags: android

I just want to concatenate action bar headercolor

```
String mycolor="#dddd"

getSupportActionBar().setTitle("<font color=mycustomcolor'></font>");
```

there is error showing

Comment: just parsing my string <font color=mycustomcolor'></font>

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Html.fromHtml](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int))**

> Returns displayable styled text from the provided HTML string.

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#54D66A'>HII</font>"));
```

For **Status Bar**

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            Window window =activity.getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#Your_Hex_Color_Code"));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks guys i was made syntaxt error in concatenation its working

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color="+headerTextColor+" size="+headerfontSize+">Hello</font>")) ;

Comment: @sowmya above code works fine here .SIZE should be NUMERIC

Comment: How can i change status bar color programatically to support all OS ?

Comment: @sowmya Staus bar coming from Android 5.0 Lollipop